# PhP Mailing Function New Line per Variable Input

Tags: php, email

I'm new to PhP and recently have an form submitted (Application) to this PhP document. The document will send the user's input information through the form to my email.

```
<?php
$ToEmail = 'example@something.com'; 
$EmailSubject = 'Applicant for Something'; 
$mailheader = "From: ".$_POST['firstname'] .$_POST['middleinitial'] .$_POST['lastname']."\n";
$mailheader .= "Reply-To: ".$_POST["email1"]."\r\n"; 
$mailheader .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n"; 
$MESSAGE_BODY = "Applicant's Full Name: ".$_POST['firstname']." ".$_POST['middleinitial']." ".$_POST['lastname']." \n";
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Email: ".$_POST['email']." \n ";
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Phone: ".$_POST['phone']." \n ";
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "State: ".$_POST['state']." \n ";
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Gender: ".$_POST['gender']." \n ";
mail($ToEmail, $EmailSubject, $MESSAGE_BODY, $mailheader) or die ("Failure to Submit"); 
exit();
?>
```

However, the slightest details bother me, and whenever I receive an email, it looks somewhat like this in the body:

```
Applicant's Full Name: John A Smith Email:
johnsmith@example.com Phone:
555-555-5555 State: MA Gender:
Male
```

All the information is on the same line. I have spent more than 4 hours researching an answer, tried various solutions, and this continues to not work. I would rather each topic be on a separate line. This may just be the device I am viewing the emails on is all I have determined.

```
" \n"
```

seems not to work in any form. I've tried over and over. Thanks so much in advance. The least you could do is tell me that it is my viewing device I receive the emails with (Apple iPhone), or that it is impossible. Least I could quit then. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If you have set your Context-type to `text/html` then using `\n` (carriage return) is not going to work. You should try using `<br />` or any other HTML tag that you wish to add line breaks.